# Getting the AD Groups using ADAL within an iOS Xamarin app

Tags: c#, active-directory, xamarin.ios, adal

Is there a possible framework or connection to make to make it possible to receive the AD Groups an user is part of using Azure AD from a Xamarin iOS app.

I have the authentication part down using ADAL but in the iOS app I want to display certain parts or hide certain parts based on what roles the user has within the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get group information you should use the [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/).  You'll need to add some delegated permissions to your app in the Azure Portal, then sign in the user, and finally can make an http request to get the group info providing the access token from the authentication.

The endpoints that will be useful for doing group operations are listed out [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/group).